# Inherit color palettes in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I want to create a very simple color palette in QML, something like this:

```
QtObject {
  property color foreground
  property color background
  property color primary
  property color secondary
}
```

I then want to be able to set a palette for a component and have all (custom) child controls of that component inherit the palette automatically. Either to the bottom of the component tree, or until I set another palette on one of those children.

```
+ root (Palette A)
+- child (inherit Palette A)
+-- child (inherit Palette A)
+- child (Palette B)
+-- child (inherit Palette B)
```

Is this possible somehow?

Edit: The way I currently thought about doing this is to just create a `colorPalette` property in the `root` component and reference it from the `child` components. Whenever I want to override the current palette I could just add a `colorPalette` property to `child`.
This would work ofcourse, I don't think it's a very clean solution though, because then I can only use my components when there is a global `colorPalette` property. Furthermore this could lead to naming conflicts later on.

Comment: What did you already do? What problems did you face? Please note that SO is not a learning resource.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, I edited my post.

Comment: Please post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of describing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, considering that the properties of any root element will be visible to all nested elements, directly or not, via dynamic scoping, unless they get shadowed, it shouldn't be that hard to accomplish what you want.

All you need to do is carefully name your properties so they don't get shadowed. And from then on, if you do a `someprop: somevalue`, that will try to find `somevalue` and resolve it to the first one that it finds.

It would have been nice if QML had interfaces and multiple inheritance for such, unfortunately there isn't any, nor even macro support to avoid the excessive copy-pasting and associated maintenance issues that come with it.

If you are going for a nesting approach, I suggest you use `Item` instead of `QtObject`, because the latter cannot really have children. The nesting approach will ultimately lead to overheads, because you will have to have an instance of a palette every time you want to nest something in it.

The other solution is to use a `QtObject` property, this way you can assign numerous instances of it to a single palette object. But then you will also manually have to implement that property for each object that is supposed to provide paletting and every time you want to reference a color, you would have to do `palette.colorValue` rather than just `colorValue` and no palette property, just a palette nesting adapter. That is not to say that the nesting approach would be less verbose, as with it it is very likely to run into the layouting issues of using a nesting item, which will too require code to work around.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I chose to use the dynamic scoping approach for now. I was hoping there is a cleaner solution, though, that doesn't fail when `colorPalette` is undefined.

Comment: @JohannesStricker you can failsafe that by checking if it is undefined.

Comment: Yeah, I know. This quickly gets messy if I have to check it in many spots though. Maybe I could do something like `property ColorPalette _colorPalette: colorPalette || ColorPalette{}`.